# Implicit dependency to json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar causes build to fail, even though it's been excluded in build.gradle

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-3.0

I'm converting an existing Maven based project containing a Grails 2.4.2 application to Gradle 2.6 and Grails 3.0.4. It's a mixed environment with Java, Groovy, and Grails used in several sub-projects. I've converted all the pom.xml files into build.gradle files, starting off with ./gradlew init, and then hand editing as needed. Before converting the Grails project's grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy to the build.gradle equivalent, everything built fine with Gradle 2.6. After I converted the Grails project's BuildConfig.groovy file to build.gradle, I'm getting the following error when trying to run ./gradlew build:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':foo:runtime'.
> Could not find json-lib-jdk15.jar (net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4).
Searched in the following locations:
  file:/Users/xyz/.m2/repository/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

The json-lib-2.4.jar file does exist in the local M2 cache shown above, but it doesn't have the -jdk15 part in it. There's no explicit dependency to any json-lib jar file in the build.gradle file for the Grails project. A parallel project does have an explicit dependency on this library, but that project builds fine. I've tried to explicitly add the dependency to the build.gradle file in the Grails project both with and without **"classifier: 'jdk15'"** to the dependency declaration. When I ran ./gradlew dependencies, I noticed that an older version (2.3) of the json-lib jar file showed up in the list as an implied dependency for some Apache HttpComponent stuff. I then tried both versions of this in the allProjects section of the top level build.gradle:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'json-lib'
}
```

as well as:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'json-lib', classifier: 'jdk15'
}
```

Neither variant makes any difference. I'm really stuck on this and would appreciate any tips on how to move forward. In case it makes a difference, I'm running this on a Mac with MacOS 10.10.5, the JDK version is 1.8.0_25-b17. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
dependencies {
    //compile group: 'net.sf.json-lib', name: 'json-lib', version: '2.4'
    compile "net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4:jdk15"
}
```

Comment: Please edit this answer to provide some additional context, or explanation as to why this solves the problem.

Comment: @wuke, your example contains exactly `json-lib:2.4` which I was trying to include to my test dependencies. Thank you! :D